# Get data from pivot table eloquent

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to fetch data from pivot table, but it says "Trying to get property 'tags' of non-object". Also find(1) in controller doesn't return anything, even though the table has some data.

My models:

```
class Videos extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'videos';
    function tags(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Videos\Tags','tag_video','video_id','tag_id');

    }


class Tags extends Model
{

    function videos(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Videos\Videos','tag_video', 'tag_id','video_id');
    }
}
```

My controller:

```
 public function fetch(){
        $videos_from_supercategories =
        $videos_with_tags = Videos::find(1);
        $tags = $videos_with_tags->tags->first();

      $data['tags']=$tags;

        return $data;
    }
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

`Videos::find(1)` is trying to find video with id = 1, if this isnt presented it return nothing and you get the exception, you can use `findOrFail(1)`.

The findOrFail will throw model not found exception, you want this to happen because otherwise you are trying to access properties on a non-object.

In you relation you have to specify what columns you want to include:

```
public function fetch()
{
    return Videos::findOrFail(1)->tags->first()->pivot->column1;
}

class Videos extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'videos';
    function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Videos\Tags','tag_video','video_id','tag_id')->withPivot('column1', 'column2');
    }
}
```

Comment: Using withPivot in Model helped, but i just had to use: $tags=Videos::with('tags')->get(); in controller. Thank you :)